# Firefox Addon SDK content script to intercept window.navigator calls?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I have this code to log calls to a bunch of window.navigator properties:

```
        var navigatorProperties = [ "appCodeName", "appMinorVersion", "appName", "appVersion", "cookieEnabled", "cpuClass", "onLine", "opsProfile", "platform", "product", "systemLanguage", "userAgent", "userLanguage", "userProfile" ];

        var contentStorage = {}; 

        navigatorProperties.forEach(
            function(property) {
                contentStorage["window.navigator." + property] = window.navigator[property];

                Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, property, {
                    configurable: true,
                    get: function() { logValue("window.navigator." + property, contentStorage["window.navigator." + property], "get"); return contentStorage["window.navigator." + property] },
                    set: function(value) { logValue("window.navigator." + property, contentStorage["window.navigator." + property], "set"); contentStorage["window.navigator." + property] = value; } 
                });
            });
```

When this code lives in a regular web page, any calls to the defined and watch properties like console.log('local page: ' + window.navigator.product); work correctly, that is, I get logValue execution output.  However, I want this code to live in an addon SDK built extension content injected script that I inject through a a page mod API.  When I do that, and go to a page that modifies or accesses a property I watch, logValue is never fired.  I've tried replacing window with unsafeWindow but also no luck.  Anyone has any pointers for me as to why this code isn't working when injected through an addon?